# I want to implement radial blur in swift/swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, blur, radial

I want to implement radial blur in swift/swiftui. Found Radial gradient on cifilter. Is is possible to make radial blur using radial gradient and cimaskedvariableblur? Or any other apporch?

[image: blur image]

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-filter-images-using-core-image-and-cifilter and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/integrating-core-image-with-swiftui